# RoR: calling a javascript function in application.js from a form_for helper in my view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I have a view (edit.html.erb) with the a form_for helper written as such:

```
<%= form_for(@user, html: { class: "directUpload" }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :avatarurl %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatarurl %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

After much trouble with this code, I finally placed .directUpload right in my application.js with an alert to see if I was even getting a call from my form_for.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function() {
  alert('got here 1');
  $(".directUpload input[type=file]").each(function(i, elem) {
    alert('got here 2');
    .
    .
    .
```

Result: nothing. Apparently, my trouble all along has been the call to my function?!

Any help would be appreciated. Please keep in mind that I'm a new to Rails!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check error console and see if there are any errors.  also, try to put an alert before $('.directupload') and see if it makes it into the doc ready function.

Comment: i put alerts just before $(function() { and just after... still nothing.

Comment: check network panel and make sure the application.js is loaded.  or remove the application.js script tag and put the entire source inline and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry if this is too basic, but do you have the jquery-rails/jquery-turbolinks gems installed?

Comment: @MichaelCruz I doubt there's anything too basic for me. It's a good thought. I checked my Gemfile and I have 'turbolinks', '1.1.1' and 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'.

Comment: not entirely sure, but I think you may need the jquery-turbolinks gem specifically, if I remember correctly. Also, could you show your whole application.js file? It would help to see what require statements are there (they will appear commented out).

Comment: try to put another alert before $(function()

Comment: Hmm I'm curious to see what happens if you install the jquery-rails gem then replace the //= require turbolinks line with //= require jquery.turbolinks

Comment: If you're curious, you can read up on it here http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-turbolinks/0.2.1/frames. Looks like turbolinks doesn't work well with JavaScript, which is why jquery-turbolinks was released

Comment: @BennyLin I had tried that, too.

Comment: @MichaelCruz I tried your suggestion on jquery-turbolinks and got into the function! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert( $(".directUpload input[type=file]") );
```

Comment: @ChrisTauer how you launch your application? `rails s` or something else?

Comment: @ChrisTauer, have you tried to restart it or use `rails s`? It seems that it didn't reflect on changes you made in application.js

Comment: I restarted both ways... no luck. :(

Comment: @ChrisTauer do you have `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` in your `layouts\application.html.erb` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Michael's suggestion in the comments, I installed jquery-turbolinks and tinkered with the turbolinks. The call to function started working.